# How can I use the sharpen filter for photography with flutter?

Tags: flutter, filter

I am developing a photo filter application with Flutter. I could not find resources on some filters. What I want to do is; The "Sharpen" effect is given as a 3x3 matrix on the internet. I can only change color over 5x4 matrix with widgets like ColorFiltered in Flutter. Operates with ImageFilter.matrix in the same way as a 4x4 matrix. I cannot run the "Sharpen" effect with these widgets. Can you help with this?

Note: I use the PhotoFilters package, it goes sharpen, but I can't get what I want.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried ColorFiltered, I tried ImageFiltered yet I couldn't.